# how to check for mobile version of a website?

Tags: php, dom, curl

I would like to check if mobile version exists for a specific website or not. To my understanding, we cannot be sure if every website has mobile version located at http://m.example.com/ therefore I am testing through CURL() request. Here is how I am doing it:

```
* I send mobile browser headers in curl request, this returns contents of 
the returning URL. 
* If it has a mobile version, then it would return contents of a mobile version site.
* I then check if the content includes @media keyword, if it exists then I assume it has a mobile version.
```

The problem is, if its css loads externally then I will have to further send CURL() requests to the CSS files as well, which will make it even more slower. Is there any specific solution to my problem or can I boost this process a bit more?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach, which smells a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), is that it is simply unreliable.

The website has many choices for mobile websites, which include:

**1. Using CSS media queries**

The problem with this method is twofold. For starters, you would have to scan every single CSS file and `<link>` declaration. Secondly, the site can dynamically introduce stylesheets to the page using JavaScript, which you will never see using cURL because it lacks a JavaScript parser.

**2. Browser sniffing using (client side) JavaScript, or screen width sniffing using JavaScript**

Again, this JavaScript will never get executed, so you will never see that result.

**3. Browser sniffing using server side code**

Well, I guess you could try to use a mobile user-agent string with your cURL request, and see where that takes you, but all of these methods are hackish and unreliable.

**4. The page could be mobile friendly from the get-go (credit to @Quentin)**

As @Quentin mentioned in the comments, the page could be mobile friendly without any additional checks on the client/server side (responsive design without media queries, by simply using percentage-based values, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of each scenario. Well, I could not find any other option, is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: 4. They might have a website that is simply mobile friendly without any special casing for mobiles.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I guess I forgot about the most basic example, cheers. While there may be solutions to this problem, they will be hackish workarounds, not real solutions. May I ask why you require this feature?

Comment: @RainFromHeaven Sorry for late reply. Actually the website I am working on involves affiliation with third party websites. So I need to know which affiliate partner has enabled mobile site.